# Meteor initial page load very long

Tags: javascript, meteor, websocket

With my Meteor App, I recently started to encounter a very long load time on the initial page load. Inspecting the requests to/from the page, it seems the load is hanging on a websocket request:

[image: websocket req]

This issue was not present until recently and I'm not even sure how to start troubleshooting this. I'm going to start rolling back commits to see where the problem started, but any thoughts on what could cause this or where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using Meteor DevTools to inspect the calls between the client and server. It seems I unintentionally published an entire collection of 22,000 documents (and growing) to the local collections in the browser on each reload. Quick filter in the collection publish and all is resolved.